# Are there any agents to spawn a script or exe with command from Reportportal dashboard?

Tags: automated-tests, agent, reportportal

I have reportportal installation running on Windows box. I am planning to use it as dashboard to look at unit test and other automated test results. I understand reportportal integration with unit test frameworks is done at the logger level so that the test app itself can send results back to dashboard.
I have a scenario where the test application is an exe that I want to launch by sending a command from dashboard to system under test.

Are there any provisions for doing it?
Do I have to build an agent that talks to reportportal using its api for this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

No, nothing similar at the moment.
It is pretty popular request, so we have it in backlog, but still focus on test reports aggregations first. And the other types of functionality will come later.